# Alternative for using system() in C++ to prevent firing new processes

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I came across a C++ program for my use, in which there was some processing being done using some files and exes. Inside my C++ program, I had a snippet like

```
system(exe1 exe2 > TestFile1.txt  exe3 > TestFile2.txt)
system(exe2 exe3 > TestFile3.txt  exe3 > TestFile4.txt)
system(exe3 exe2 > TestFile5.txt  exe3 > TestFile6.txt)
system(exe4 exe1 > TestFile7.txt  exe3 > TestFile8.txt)
```

Now, I generated a `.dll` out of this C++ program to use in my C# app through P/Ivoke (`Dllimport`) but since the C++ had these `system` being used, it fires different processes and new cmd windows when I use this `.dll` in my C# program.

I thought to get rid of this by generating the dll's of all the exes (exe1, exe2, exe3 etc.) and firing the main function from these dlls, but it doesn't strike to me about how will I do that in C++ program?

I can export the main function from the C++ (exe1 dll, exe2 dll, exe3 dll etc.) and call it through C# P/Invoke, but I want an alternative like this for C++. to replace the above 4 line snippet. How can that be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start processes (also those which operate in text mode) without them having opening a console window. Please don't bolt me down on the details, since it's been ages since I've done this the last time (on Windows, I do it on regular terms on *nix systems). What I can tell you is, that you have to look into the function `CreateProcessEx`. You'll also have to reimplement the redirection of stdout into those textfiles.

I strongly advise against putting those processes into DLLs because then they'll run into your main process address space and **will** mess things up (BTW: You can load EXEs as if they were DLLs, but calling their entry function will b0rk your main process, so don't do it).

Comment: @daterwolf: I was told that firing such number of processes is not a good thing either. Which approach according to you weighs more? How will this mess up things if I create dlls out of these to run in a single process? Can you also clear up a bit on how calling the exes as dlls will bork the main process? The question still remains how do I even use the exe as all in my C++ program and call its main function?

Comment: @user1240679: Every executable contains a so called "run time environment" which does things like setting up the stack frame, initializing gobal/static variables and some other bookkeeping. Loading a full blown foreign executable into one own's process and calling it's entry point will make that executable's initialization code run havoc throughout your own process. Therefore: Don't even attempt this (unless you want to replace you own process executable image with the foreign executable's one). What you need to do is executing those executables in their own processes and redirect their output

Answer (score 0):

If the matter of you post that console is shown, just make your exe1...exeN invisible. Simplest way - replace

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

with

```
int WINAPI WinMain(
  HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
```

And change target from console application to windows application.

Another (and better solution) is convert you application to multiple DLLs with functions - this is more elegant and flexible.

**EDITED**

After clarification of problem: *"how do I call the functions in these dll's then?"* short answer is: you need export function from each dll exe1,..exeN. Full answer - follow instructions:

In your dll declare

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) SameNameForAllDllFunction(LPCWSTR fileName){ ...
```

This will create function that can be exported by name `_SameNameForAllDllFunction`. Note that name of file is unicode - it will simplify communication with C#.

Now let's write C# part:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private delegate void DoSomeWithFile(String fileName);
```

This declares type of function. And code of invocation:

```
IntPtr pDll = NativeMethods.LoadLibrary(@"exe1.DLL");
//here MUST go error handlers
try{
    IntPtr pAddressOfFunctionToCall = NativeMethods.GetProcAddress(
        pDll, "SameNameForAllDllFunction");
    //here MUST go error handlers
    DoSomeWithFile dllFunct = (DoSomeWithFile)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(
        pAddressOfFunctionToCall, typeof(DoSomeWithFile)); 
    dllFunct("TestFile1.txt"); //now call the function 
} finally {
    NativeMethods.FreeLibrary(pDll);
}
```

Comment: I am not sure I get this properly. I can convert from `exe's` to dlls but how do I use them in C++ program then instead of system. This would prevent firing processes, and also opening consoles.

Comment: The consoles are also fired because I have used `system` in my C++. How would I hide these console windows then?

Comment: @user1240679 (1) If you can modify these applications by replacing main->WinMain - this can hide console appearing. (2) If you can modify these applications you can convert them also to DLLs (3) May be you cannot modify these apps to DLL - then let me know, I'll provide another solution.

Comment: @user1240679 `system` should be replaced with `CreateProcessEx`

Comment: When I call the WinMain() function from C# through `DllImport`, so this won't launch any console?
I can modify the programs to get all dll's instead of exe1, exe2 etc. but my question is that how do I call the functions in these dll's then? Since the dll's will the not have an entry point, how do I call the dll main function in my C++ program? For e.g.: How will I do this `CreateProcessEx(exe1 exe2 > TestFile1.txt  exe3 > TestFile2.txt)` if I do not have exe1, exe2, exe3 but have dll's instead of these exes?

Comment: @user1240679 just added description how to call dll function